# When is it useful to set the mustUnderstand flag to "false" for a SOAP header?

Tags: soap

I just read this example in anthoer thread:

"imagine the header is for transaction semantics (i.e. the call must be performed within a transaction so that operations are performed in an atomic way, either all succeeding or all failing). If the processing node sees the transaction header it should start that transaction. Imagine what would happen if the node sees the header but does not know what it is so it decides to just ignore it and no transaction is started. Later, some operations fail while other succeed and there is no transaction to rollback. So now your application is in an inconsistent state."
([what does it mean to "understand" a soap header tagged "mustunderstand"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234380/what-does-it-mean-to-understand-a-soap-header-tagged-mustunderstand))

I understand that we set the mustUnderstand flag to "true" if there is information in the header that must be processed and taken into account, but is there an example for information in the header that is non critical, so we can set the mustUnderstand flag to "false"? If it's optional to process the information in the header, why provide it then?
Are there methods that work better when provided with additional information but still work without it?