# .Net is messing up SOAP request format

Tags: soap, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

0

I am using .net6 to connect to a SOAP service.

Here is the body that they expect to receive.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.me.com/cpm/xsd/mcpservices/security/v1" xmlns:v11="http://www.me.com/cpm/xsd/mcpservices/cardholdermanagement/v1" xmlns:v12="http://www.me.com/cpm/xsd/mcpservices/base/v1">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v1:requestSecurity>
         <v1:userName/>
         <v1:senderId>Test Desktop</v1:senderId>
         <v1:correlationId>000001</v1:correlationId>
         <v1:prel>122</v1:prel>
      </v1:requestSecurity>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v11:cardAvailablityRequest>
         <v12:servicingCentre>90</v12:servicingCentre>
         <v12:channel>WEB</v12:channel>
         <v11:prel>122</v11:prel>
         <v11:lastFourOfCardNumber>2222</v11:lastFourOfCardNumber>
      </v11:cardAvailablityRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However if I look at the request I am sending via the

Request.Content.Message

property

I see this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:checkCardAvailability</Action>
    <h:requestSecurity xmlns:h="http://www.me.com/cpm/xsd/mcpservices/security/v1" xmlns="http://www.me.com/cpm/xsd/mcpservices/security/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <userName>name</userName>
      <senderId>Test Desktop</senderId>
      <correlationId>000001</correlationId>
      <prel>122</prel>
    </h:requestSecurity>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <h:cardAvailablityRequest>
         <servicingCentre>90</v12:servicingCentre>
         <channel>WEB</v12:channel>
         <prel>122</v11:prel>
         <cardNumber>2222</v11:cardNumber>
      </h:cardAvailablityRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What on earth is going on? I used their WSDL to automatically create the proxy classes etc in Visual Studio. I would have thought those classes would form the SOAP correctly?

The WSDL has no instances of the text V11 or V12 so I have no idea how it could possibly know to put those in the Body...

Interestingly if I import the WSDL into SOAPUI it produces the correct Request format (Identical to the top request). Why is .net corrupting the format?

Comment: V11 and V12 are XML namespace prefixes. As long as they point to the correct namespace you could even call them "pineapple". The XML parser should not care, unless who built the web service had no idea what they were doing. I haven't read the messages thoroughly, but it seems the only difference is the extra Action header, which might be an issue, or might not, depending on the server [if it understands the header or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234380/what-does-it-mean-to-understand-a-soap-header-tagged-mustunderstand)